# What is meteor Session.equals used for?

Tags: meteor

What does session.equals do in meteor and what is it used for and how is this different from session.set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Session.equals helps to check if something is equal to the value. For example.

```
Session.set("foo", "foo");
Session.equals("foo", "bar"); => false;

Session.set("foo", "bar");
Session.equals("foo", "bar"); => true;
```

It just tells you whether the value is equal to the value you specify, similar to doing `Session.get("foo") == "bar"`

#### Why would one need this, `Session.get` is good enough!?

Whats the point of it if it does something so simple? Meteor uses the idea of reactivity and every time you change the value of something the helpers have to re-run.

If you use `Session.equals` it ensures that the helper re-runs very minimally since the change can only be `true` or `false`. It was built for the sake of efficiency in your app so the html doesn't have to be checked & changed.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks and with support like this I'm sure meteor will be as popular as jquery is now. Great community!!

Comment: @james Please remember to mark this answer as accepted (and upvote?) if it's solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how `equals` makes things faster, it would be great if you could expand on that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation makes this pretty clear](http://docs.meteor.com/#session_equals)

`Session.equals` is for comparing a key's value in the session to the provided value, similar to `Session.get("key") === "compare to value"`.  However, the documentation recommends you use `Session.equals` in this case so there are fewer redraws.

`Session.equals` returns `true` or `false` based on the comparison.

`Session.set` actually sets the value for the given key in the session.  This is totally different.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I think the other answer helps explain the redraw part better but massively appreciate your help :-)